# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/main/div/section/div/section/div/div/ul/li[1]/a"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

The chrome browser version is Version 115.0.5790.171 and downloaded chrome driver version is 114
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

as driver version 115 is not available.

I'm using the x-path and checked the x-path is correct or not in developer tool under console section it is correct. Even tried absolute path given by Automation Tester but still getting as **No such element is found**
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

This x-path is getting due to chrome browser version is 115 and chrome driver version is 114 using due to unavailable.

Could someone please help me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnSVN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydrhs.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXedl.png

Comment: apparently the new web driver for chrome 115.0.5790.171 hasn't been added yet the latest version of web driver is 115.0.5790.170

Answer (score 0):

1. The newer version of ChromeDriver are normally available at https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ page:

   [image]
2. It might be the case you're trying to find the element which is not in [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) yet, consider using [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)
3. It might be the case the element is not displayed in the viewport, you might need to [maximize](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#maximize()) the browser window
4. It might be the case you're trying to find the element which resides in an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP) or in [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM), in this case you first need to switch to that frame or [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) beforehand.

More information: [How to Automate Selenium UI Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selenium-ui-tests)